# Base cases in strong induction proofs (postage example)

Tags: proof-writing, solution-verification, proof-explanation, induction

Let $P(n)$ be the statement "an $n$-cent postage can be produced using 3-cent stamps and/or 10-cent stamps". I prove in three different ways that $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}_{\geq 18} P(n)$ by strong induction. I'd like to identify eventual flaws in each proof and to know what do you think about each approach. The matter I want to discuss is the treatment of the base cases. I've read in several places that people often handle what would be the base case(s) in the inductive step to fix an eventual gap, rather than explicitly proving them beforehand as a basis (as it's done in weak induction proofs). Personally, I found **Proof 2** the simplest of the three, although **Proof 1** is somewhat standard for this particular problem. Do you think the approach I followed in **Proof 2** should be the default for strong induction proofs? What about **Proof 3**?

**Proof 1:** 
*Basis*: 
If $n=18$, then six 3-cent stamps are needed. 
If $n=19$, then one 10-cent and three 3-cent stamps are needed. 
If $n=20$, then two 10-cent stamps are needed. 
Thus, $P(18)$, $P(19)$, and $P(20)$ are true. 
*Step*: 
Fix $n \geq 20$. Suppose $P(k)$ is true for all $18 \leq k \leq n$, that it, a $k$-cent stamp can be produced using 3-cent stamps and/or 10-cent stamps. We prove that $P(n+1)$ is true. 
Since $n \geq 20$, then $n-2 \geq 18$. Then, by the induction hypothesis, $P(n-2)$ is true. Thus, we add a 3-cent stamp to an $(n-2)$-cent postage and produce an $(n+1)$-cent postage. Therefore, $P(n+1)$ is true.

**Proof 2:** 
Fix $n \geq 18$. Suppose $P(k)$ is true for all $18 \leq k \leq n$, that it, a $k$-cent stamp can be produced using 3-cent stamps and/or 10-cent stamps. We prove that $P(n+1)$ is true. There are three cases to consider: 
If $n=18$, then six 3-cent stamps are needed. 
If $n=19$, then one 10-cent stamp and three 3-cent stamps are needed. 
If $n \geq 20$, then $n-2 \geq 18$. Then, by the induction hypothesis, $P(n-2)$ is true. Thus, we add a 3-cent stamp to an $(n-2)$-cent postage and produce an $(n+1)$-cent postage. Therefore, $P(n+1)$ is true.

**Proof 3:** 
Fix $n \geq 18$. Suppose $P(k)$ is true for all $18 \leq k \leq n$, that it, a $k$-cent stamp can be produced using 3-cent stamps and/or 10-cent stamps. We prove that $P(n+1)$ is true. There are three cases to consider: 
If $n+1=19$, then one 10-cent stamp and three 3-cent stamps are needed. 
If $n+1=20$, then two 10-cent stamp are needed. 
If $n+1 \geq 21$, then $n-2 \geq 18$. Then, by the induction hypothesis, $P(n-2)$ is true. Thus, we add a 3-cent stamp to an $(n-2)$-cent postage and produce an $(n+1)$-cent postage. Therefore, $P(n+1)$ is true.

**Edit**: I included the following proof that is somewhat different from the previous regarding the treatment of "base cases". This one is not of my authorship, and was acquired from this Problem Set from MIT (freely available online) with some modifications: https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-042j-mathematics-for-computer-science-fall-2005/lecture-notes/cp3fsol.pdf.

**Proof 4:** 
Suppose $P(n)$ is true for all $n \geq 18$. We prove that $P(n+1)$ is true. There are five cases:

1. $n+1$ < 18: So $P(n+1)$ holds vacuously.
2. $n+1 = 18$: $P(n+1)$ holds because we produce an 18-cent postage using six 3-cent stamps.
3. $n+1 = 19$: $P(n+1)$ holds by using one 10-cent stamp and three 3-cent stamps.
4. $n+1 = 20$: $P(n+1)$ holds by using two 10-cent stamps.
5. $n+1 > 20$: We have $n \geq 20$, so $n-2 \geq 18$. Then, by the induction hypothesis, $P(n-2)$ is true. Thus, we add a 3-cent stamp to an $(n-2)$-cent postage and produce an $(n+1)$-cent postage. Therefore, $P(n+1)$ is true.

I'm having some trouble to understand why they put case (1) and (2). As was written in the comments, case (2) will never be true. As for case (1), why is it treated in this proof?

Comment: I don't think there is a significant difference to any of them to warrant any discussion.

Comment: I'm in the minority but I prefer.  $10 -3\times 3= 3\times 7 - 2\times 10$.  So if $P(k)$ is true and $k = 10a + 3b;k \ge 18;a,b\ge 0$, then $k+1 = 10(a+1) + 3(b-3) = 10(a-2)+3(b+7)$.  If $b < 3$ then $18 \le k = 10a + 3b < 10a + 9$ so $10a> 9$ so $a \ge 2$. So let $a'=a-2\ge 0; b'=b+7\ge 7>0$ so $k+1 = 10a' + 3b'$.  If $a<2$ then $18\le=10a+3b\le 10 + 3b$ so $8\le 3b$ so $b\ge 3$.  So let $b'=b-3\ge 0$ and $a'=a+1 \ge 1>0$ and $k+1=10a'+3b'$.  If $a\ge 2;b\ge 3$ then you can chose either $(a',b')=(a-2,b+7)$ or $a',b'=(a+1,b-3)$ Either way we get $a',b'\ge 0$ and $k+1=10a'+3b'$. So $P(k+1)$ .

Comment: But *nobody* but me likes that way of doing it.

Comment: @LucasPeres There are a couple of minor issues with you proofs. First, in your "Proof 1", the $n = 19$ case is missing that three $3$-cent stamps are also needed. Second, in your "Proof 3", since $n \gt 18$, your first case of $n + 1 = 18$ will never be true. Regarding which proof to use, I agree with fleablood's first comment in that I also don't see any particularly significant difference between them.

Comment: @JohnOmielan Just fixed Proof 1, that was a typo. As for Proof 3, you are right. If I remove the $n+1=18$ case, it would still work, right? Now, I didn't have the intention to discuss the content of these proofs, since as you two observed, they are very similar. I wanted to know from more experienced people what they think about the treatment of base cases in strong induction proofs. I've seen some people omit the base case(s) completely in this kind of proof. Perhaps the examples I chose are not very good for that matter, unfortunately... :(

Comment: Just removed the $n+1=18$ case from Proof 3.

Comment: @LucasPeres Yes, removing the $n + 1 = 18$ case doesn't affect the validity of Proof $3$, as I see you've already done. As for the base case(s) in an induction proof, they are technically required for a fully complete proof. Nonetheless, I believe some people may just skip explicitly mentioning them in some cases where they consider it to be trivial or obvious, especially if these base case(s) are already mentioned earlier, e.g., as part of the conditions stated for the problem.

Comment: Fellows, I added Proof 4 from a problem set from MIT. That was one of the proofs I saw around that bothered me a lot. I'm starting to have the feeling that it's wrong.